# Deploying content from a staging site to production with the, Heroku, CKEditor gem, Paperclip and Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, ckeditor, paperclip

I have a rails site that utilizes ckeditor so the user can build pages on the site. Generally they develop pages on a staging site and push the changes to a production server. Before the user was hosting the site and any images on a private server, so ckeditor was using relative paths for images. For example, in the content field of ckeditor created asset:

```
img src=\"/uploads/images/mypic.jpeg\"
```

However, we're now transitioning to Heroku and we're using Amazon S3 to host the files. As a result, ckeditor has to use absolute paths. For example:

```
img src=\"http://mybucket_staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/images/mypic.jpeg\"
```

This makes deploying from staging to production problematic because even tho the correct picture is in the production bucket, the content field of the ckeditor assets will still be pointing at the staging bucket when the database is pushed to production. Is there anyway to make this more dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) - one that's set differently on production and staging - and populate the path from the value of this variable?

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this. Before the ckeditor asset is saved, we do a gsub on the url that replaces the bucket url depending on the environment. Basically:


`def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   @article.content.gsub(/src=(.*?)\/uploads/, "src=\"http://#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}/uploads")`